# Incorrect reference to child control when user control is reused in page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

Adding a user control that accepts a few properties and is used to be able to generically set different configuration values within our application.

There are instances where this will require two of these controls to be used on the same page. We are using Telerik ASP.Net for Ajax controls however this should not be specific to the Telerik suite. Code is below, but a simple breakdown of the control is as follow:

config control

- open button
- container window that is hidden

  - text box
  - submit button

The open button is displayed on the page the user controls live in. Clicking this button does not trigger postback and uses javascript to open the container window.

Once open, the value can be updated and the submit button triggers post back, submits the change, and closes the window.

My problem is this:
When I place two of these controls on the same page for different values, the JavaScript that opens the window lives inside the control and is duplicated in the page and is sometimes referencing and opening the wrong window. How can I address this?

```js
    function OpenWindow(sender, args) {
        $find('<%= windowControlID.ClientID %>').show();
    }
```

Control is added to the parent page like so:

```html
<span style="display:block;">
    <uc:UpdateConfigurationValue id="configvalue1" runat="server" ConfigurationName="configValueName1" ConfigurationDescription="configValueDescription1" ConfigurationValueContext="configValueContext1" buttonWidth="100%" TelerikSkin="MetroTouch" FieldSecurityID="###" />
</span>
<span style="display:block;">
    <uc:UpdateConfigurationValue id="configValue2" runat="server" ConfigurationName="configValueName2" ConfigurationDescription="configValueDescription2" ConfigurationValueContext="configValueContext2" buttonWidth="100%" TelerikSkin="MetroTouch" FieldSecurity="###" />
</span>
```

User control markup:

```html
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UpdateConfigurationValue.ascx.vb" Inherits="JearLogistics.UpdateConfigurationValue" %>

<telerik:RadButton id="btnUpdateConfigurationValue" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" OnClientClicked="btnUpdateConfigurationValue_OnClientClicked" />

<telerik:RadWindow ID="rwUpdateConfigurationValue" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" Behaviors="Default" VisibleStatusbar="false" ReloadOnShow="true" AutoSize="true" AutoSizeBehaviors="WidthProportional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <center>
            <div>
                <telerik:radlabel ID="lblConfigurationDescription" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch"/>:
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtConfigurationValue" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" />
                <telerik:RadLabel ID="lblConfigurationValueContext" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSubmitConfigurationChange" runat="server" AutoPostback="true" Skin="MetroTouch" Text="Submit" />
            </div>
        </center>
    </ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow>

<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="codeBlockUpdateConfigurationValue" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function btnUpdateConfigurationValue_OnClientClicked(sender, args) {
            $find("<%= rwUpdateConfigurationValue.ClientID %>").show();
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Usercontrol code behind

````
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Public Class UpdateConfigurationValue
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

#Region "Generic Properties"
    Public Property ConfigurationName As String
    Public Property ConfigurationDescription As String
    Public Property ConfigurationValueContext As String

    Public Property ButtonWidth As Unit
    Public Property TelerikSkin As String
    Public Property FieldSecurityID As Long? = Nothing

    Private ReadOnly Property FieldSecurity As Dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)
        ``` private security getters/setters
    End Property
    Private _FieldSecurity As Dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)

#End Region

#Region "Post Update Deletgate"
    Public Delegate Sub OnSubmitButtonClicked()
    Public Property AfterSubmitButtonClicked As OnSubmitButtonClicked
#End Region

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then

            If FieldSecurityID IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not FieldSecurity(FieldSecurityID) Then
                btnUpdateConfigurationValue.Visible = False
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If Not ButtonWidth.IsEmpty Then btnUpdateConfigurationValue.Width = ButtonWidth
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TelerikSkin) Then btnUpdateConfigurationValue.Skin = TelerikSkin
            btnUpdateConfigurationValue.Text = $"Update {ConfigurationDescription}"

            Dim configItem As New TblConfiguration(ConfigurationName)
            lblConfigurationValueContext.Text = ConfigurationValueContext
            lblConfigurationDescription.Text = ConfigurationDescription

            txtConfigurationValue.Text = configItem.Value
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SubmitConfigurationChange_Click(sender As RadButton, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitConfigurationChange.Click
        Dim configItem As New TblConfiguration(ConfigurationName) With {
            .Value = txtConfigurationValue.Text
        }
        configItem.Update()

        Dim afterSubmitButtonClicked As OnSubmitButtonClicked = Me.AfterSubmitButtonClicked
        If afterSubmitButtonClicked IsNot Nothing Then afterSubmitButtonClicked()

    End Sub
End Class
````

Comment: Sounds like you have two controls with the same ClientID. You can confirm that by viewing the html of the generated page. If that is the case, you can change ClientIDMode attribute of the control to generate unique ClientID.

Comment: ClientIDs are different. I have confirmed using javascript alerts to output them. Have also updated the clientIdMode to try and manage this but Telerik has a bug that causes the radwindow to fail to display content when the clientIdMode is changed to Static or Predictable. Their docs say it is fixed however it is still the same behavior in their most recent versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While researching this myself, the simplest solution was to enable postback on the button and then use responseScripts / startup scripts to show the desired window. This works well because while the javascript loaded in with the control is looking at the contents of the page, the children controls are the only thing in scope of the user control without deliberately stepping up to the page.

The snippet below was pulled from [Telerik's documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/troubleshooting/opening-from-the-server) and is left as the generic code they provide:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'business logic goes here

    Dim script As String = "function f(){$find(""" + RadWindow1.ClientID + """).show(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);"
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", script, True)
End Sub
```